# CISCO WAN without Dedicated/Static IP

Tags: static-ip, cisco-router

I have some CISCO devices (firewalls & switches)

I intend to set up a WAN between two locations but both locations are dynamic IP (residential broadband).

The IP's of each location do not change regularly but they do change "occasionally".

I am new to CISCO networking, and have sought documentation about this, but to no avail.

The WAN is not production crucial as it is for private / learning purposes.

**Q**. Is there any known documentation that would advise the best practise for this kind of network?

Comment: Anything you setup will work until the IP changes, then you're simply have to modify both routers to indicate the new IP. If you're hoping for some connection that can auto-recover/fix-itself after IP change I'm not personally aware of anything that supports that. Might want to put the models of equipment you have so that people know what TYPE of connections your equipment can make. I'm thinking of a VPN, but I know there is an OSPF or something like that too, a tunnel betweens two WAN connections

Comment: @gregg ASA5505 VPN | I know that something like DDNS could work, but im currently reading through the web to ascertain a way to use this with my nameservers in an "automated" way.

Comment: DDNS reports to a name server (for humans to easily remember a website vs changing IP), you'd have to have the router automatically reconfigure itself/VPN with that new DDNS record. That might work if you can configure the internal VPN server (of the router) with a hostname vs IP which I'm guessing is unlikely, but DO share your results/homework if you find out different